# Java Regular Expression for Syslog Message not working

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to develop a Java program that matches syslog messages.

The pattern is like this:

```
"%FACILITY-[SUBFACILITY-]SEVERITY-MNEMONIC: description"
```

At first I did this regex and it worked for some messages:

```
(%[a-zA-Z_-]+-[0-6]-[a-zA-Z_-]+[^\r\t\n]+)
```

Now I need to match only the part before the ":" (i.e, %FACILITY-[SUBFACILITY-]SEVERITY-MNEMONIC) so I'm doing the following, which does not work:

```
(%[a-zA-Z_-]+-[0-6]-[a-zA-Z_-]+)
```

I've found some online test pages and the surprising thing is that on the first one the string matches, but not the second (this one is for Java code).

http://www.regexr.com/ -> Match

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html  -> Does not match

This are the strings I'm trying to match:

```
%HA-REDCON-4-FAILOVER_REQUEST[0x767443be74] Record Reboot History, reboot cause = 0x4000004, descr = Cause: Initiating switch-over.
```

`%ROUTING-FIB-3-ASSERT` error message may occur when doing a RCC check.

Anyone has any idea about this? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To match everything before `:`, use `^[^:]+` regex. See https://regex101.com/r/kW5uY4/1 (it will work with Java, too). Just do not use "matches", since it checks the whole string capture. Or, use a capturing group with `matches`: `([^:]+):.*`.

Comment: If @stribizhev 's answer was helpful, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

To match everything before `:`, use `^[^:]+` regex.

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kW5uY4/1) (it will work with Java, too, with `find()`).

The `matches()` in Java just must match the whole string, that is why regexplanet.com says there is no match (but `find()` shows success).

If you want to use `matches()`, you need to extend the regex to the string end, and only grab the first capturing group: `([^:]+):.*`.

Here is a link to a [sample program showing how to capture multiple matches](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMV1puOTctN2htY1U).

```
String str = "%ROUTING-FIB-3-ASSERT more words here\n%HA-REDCON-4-FAILOVER_REQUEST[0x767443be74] Record Reboot History, reboot cause = 0x4000004, descr = Cause: Initiating switch-over.";
String rx = "(?i)(%[a-z_-]+-[0-6]-[a-z_-]+)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually could do it for those cases with the colon. However, now I need a match for messages that do not have the colon, for example: %ROUTING-FIB-3-ASSERT error message may occur when doing a RCC check   do u know which regex can match this?

Comment: Are these all the requirements, or will there be more? Well, for those, you can certainly use your own regex `(?i)(%[a-z_-]+-[0-6]-[a-z_-]+)`, but you'd better use it with `Matcher.find()` method. Do you want me to provide sample Java code? Here is a sample program: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMV1puOTctN2htY1U